Cannot upload photo to firebase storage due to google gms error
I am trying to make an application that captures an image and saves it to Firebase storage.
this is the code that is responsible for uploading the photo
private fun uploadAbsensi(bitmap: Bitmap, currentDate: String, currentTime: String) {
    val userId = "testID" //should have no relevance to the issue
    val absensiRef = db.collection("absensi")
        .document(userId)
        .collection("harian")
        .document(currentDate)

    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

    absensiRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot : DocumentSnapshot ->
        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Anda sudah melakukan absensi hari ini", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            // Upload photo to Firebase Storage
            val storageRef = storage.reference.child("absensi/${userId}/${currentDate}.jpg")
            val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
            val data = baos.toByteArray()

            val uploadTask = storageRef.putBytes(data)
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {
                storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    // Save attendance data to Firestore
                    val absensiData = mapOf(
                        "userId" to userId,
                        "photoUrl" to uri.toString(),
                        "date" to currentDate,
                        "time" to currentTime
                    )
                    absensiRef.set(absensiData).addOnSuccessListener {
                        Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Absensi berhasil disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//                        finish()  // Return after successful attendance
                    }
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Gagal mengunggah foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

this is my build.gradle (app-level)
plugins {
//    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)

    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.if570_f_000000068544_kevinwijayahadinata_uts"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.if570_f_000000068544_kevinwijayahadinata_uts"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.annotation)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.firebase.firestore.ktx)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.legacy.support.v4)
    implementation(libs.androidx.recyclerview)
    implementation(libs.firebase.storage.ktx)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.4.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.7.1")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.3.1")
    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2")
}

and my project-level build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
}

however, when i try to upload the image to the storage I get this error
Failed to get service from broker.  (Ask Gemini)
java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2390)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2374)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2357)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2299)

I have imported every relevant library in the fragment where my uploadAbsensi() function lies (given that there are no errors in the file), and in my firebase I have set the rules to be able to read and write data. I have never created an android app before, so please forgive my lack of knowledge if the solution is simple.
